# How to go to the numbers that are not in my data set with counts and the case statements

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2016

Would like to know why my query is not providing the number of units that are "developer units total" and the number of "is_future_residents". These are the numbers that are not in my data set and that's the number I am trying to create with the counts and the case statements. The Data set is not getting calculated by my query and that's the number I need to verify. If I try to remove "Unit_Number" it could work, this column needs to remain because it provides the individual entity unit number.

Created query with SQL Server Management Studio, my output to display correctly has parameters, and I have tried the following with my query. Query does not include the total number of developer units nor the number of future residents.

Currently my SQL SSMS query output displays the following:

```
Entity_Number   Association Name         Readable_Building_ID   Unit_Number   Number_Units  Developer_Unit_Total    Is_Future_Resident
0660            Services Association      0004                  0010          24               1                      No
0660            Services Association      0006                  0002          13               1                      No
0660            Services Association      0006                  0003          13               1                      Yes
0660            Services Association      0006                  0004          13               1                      Yes
0660            Services Association      0006                  0005          13               1                      No
```

I'm looking for a query pivot that will provide this output:

```
Entity_Number   Association Name         Readable_Building_ID   Unit_Number   Number_Units  Developer_Unit_Total    Is_Future_Resident
0660            Services Association      0004                  0010          24               1                      0
0660            Services Association      0006                  0002          13               1                      0
0660            Services Association      0006                  0003          13               1                      1
0660            Services Association      0006                  0004          13               1                      1
0660            Services Association      0006                  0005          13               1                      0
```

[Query]

```
SELECT 

ge.Entity_Number, 
ge.Name AS 'Association Name', 
bld.Readable_Building_ID,
u.Unit_Number,
bld.Number_Units,
COUNT(DISTINCT u.Unit_ID) AS 'Developer_Unit_Total',
(CASE WHEN res.Resident_Status_ID = 3 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
END) AS Is_Future_Resident


FROM  Residents AS res
INNER JOIN units AS u
ON res.Unit_ID  = u.Unit_ID

INNER JOIN buildings AS bld
ON u.Building_ID = bld.Building_ID 

INNER JOIN gl_entities AS ge
ON bld.Entity_ID = ge.Entity_ID

INNER JOIN resident_status AS rest
ON res.Status_ID = rest.Status_ID

WHERE 
u.Is_Developer_Unit = 1
AND ge.Active = 1
AND bld.Building_Active = 1

GROUP BY 
ge.Entity_Number, 
ge.Name, 
bld.Readable_Building_ID,
u.Unit_Number,
bld.Number_Units,
res.Resident_Status_ID
```

Comment: The only eiffernce I see is the formatting of the Is Future Resident changes

Comment: @Caius Jard, as you suggested, problem with formatting of the Is Future Resident? Would you have additional syntax programming demonstration for clarification?

Comment: I don't understand; you already have `(CASE WHEN res.Resident_Status_ID = 3 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)` - It hardly seems worth posting a question up just to get a recommendation of `(CASE WHEN res.Resident_Status_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)`